# Is the Canon Rebel T3/ EOS 1100D compatible with Nikon Lenses?

Tags: lens, canon, nikon

Is the Canon T3 compatible with the Sigma 18-200mm F3.5-6.3 DC OS for Nikon? I'm looking around craigslist looking for a compatible lens.

Comment: Just look for canon mount.

Answer (score 1):

Lens Manufacturers such as Sigma and Tamron make the same lens for various different camera manufacturers, however, each lens mount is different and is dedicated exclusively to that camera manufacturer.

In other words, if you wish to purchase a Sigma 18-200mm Lens for a Canon, then you need to buy a Sigma Lens with a Canon Mount I.E- EF or EF-S Fit.

The Sigma Lens dedicated for Nikon is for Nikon only and will not fit directly on the Canon camera.

it may work with an adaptor, but I doubt if you will be able to use the full auto functionality of the camera